# ドロップダウンリストの項目の値がnullになっています。

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

私はドロップダウンリストを使い選択されたの項目の値を別のテーブル(Distrip)に写したですが。ドロップダウンリストの項目の値がnullになって、項目の値を別のテーブルに写すことができません。
model とmodel classは以下の通りです。

```
public partial class LineInfo
{
     public int Line_ID { get; set; }
     public string CoID { get; set; }
     public string CoName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Distrip{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public int Line_ID { get; set; }
}
public class Modle
{
    public LineInfo lineinfo { get; set; }
    public List<Dist_Info> Distrip { get; set; }
}
```

コントローラーは以下の通りです。

```
public ActionResult Line_ID()
{
      count = db.Line_Info.Max(p => p.Line_ID);
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> line = db.LineInfo
                     .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Value = x.Line_ID.ToString(),
                         Text = x.CoName,
                     });
      ViewBag.line = line;
      view ();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Line_ID(OpeModle Ope)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var dist in Ope.Distrip)
            {
                db.Dist_Info.Add(dist);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.message = "Data successfully saved!";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Viewは狙い通り会社名が表示されています。
Viewは以下の通りです。

```
@model OpeModle

<table class="table">
            <thead border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:larger; width:800px">
                       Distriotion
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr border="1">
                <th>@Html.Label("Tili", "Line_ID ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })</th>
                <th>@Html.Label("Tili", "会社名 ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })</th>
            </tr>

            @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Distrip[i].Dist_ID, new { id = "natureOfVisitField", Value = ViewBag.countDis + i })
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.Label("Tili", "Line_ID ", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })</th>

                    <th>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Line_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.line, "Select")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Distrip[i].Line_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </th>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

デバッグしたらHttpPostにてDistripのIDが狙い通りきていますがLine_IDは0になっています。
どう直せば良いでしょうか？
ご教授をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 書いていないのでわかりませんが、`<form>`タグがループの外にあって同名のフィールドが複数存在するとかそういう理由なのでは。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。‹form›がループの中にあります。<div class = "col-md-10">の上に行に書いています。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そういう情報は質問本文に追記していただきたいです。掲載されているコードはフォームタグ以外の欠落以外にもモデル・コントローラー・ビューで記述の整合性がなく、現象を再現できない状態となっています。実際のコードから抜粋するにしても削りすぎですので、他者が検証できる程度の説明をしてください。

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。ソースを追加しました。これで再現できます。ご教授よろしくお願いします。